# Apache File Descriptor Limits

Tags: apache-2.2, file-descriptors

I'm trying to change the file descriptor limits for Apache.

The problem is that the limits set through "/etc/security/limits.conf" don't apply to system users like "apache" with no login shell.

I've tested it with this simple PHP code:

```
<?php
echo "User: ";
echo exec('whoami');
echo "<br>FD Soft Limit: ";
echo exec('ulimit -Sn');
echo "<br>FD Hard Limit: ";
echo exec('ulimit -Hn');
?>
```

I've also tried to modify a variable from "/usr/sbin/apachectl":

```
ULIMIT_MAX_FILES="ulimit -S -n `ulimit -H -n`"
```

OS: CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
Apache: Apache/2.2.15

Answer (score 1):

Are you hitting a ceiling of 1,024 file descriptors?

In CentOS/RHEL 6, a new ceiling was introduced by way of `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf`.

This file (and anything in this directory) takes precedence over `/etc/security/limits.conf`, as it's applied after limits.conf is initially read; and its default is 1,024.

See the history of this via [Red Hat Bugzilla, Bug ID #432903](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=432903).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I hit the limit `bash: cannot make pipes for command substitution: Too many open files in system`. I've tried to change these values in `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf.` however the PHP script still show the defaults (1024/4096)?